# Django Async Model Save()

Tags: django, django-views, python-asyncio

I'm converting my normal views to async views due to request queries blocking all my threads. So far I've solved most of my problems except one. How to async save a model?

```
async def dashboardAddChart(request, rowId):
    row = (await sync_to_async(list)(DashboardRow.objects.filter(pk=rowId).select_related('dashboard__site', 'dashboard__theme')))[0]

    chart = DashboardChart(dashboard=row.dashboard, dashboardRow=row)
    
    if row.dashboard.theme is not None:
        dashboardThemes.applyThemeToChart(chart)

    chart.save()

    chartData = await getChartData(chart.pk)
```

I've tried numerous things with `chart.save()` including:

```
await sync_to_async(chart.save)

t = asyncio.ensure_future(sync_to_async(chart.save))
await asyncio.gather(t)
```

But I'm not getting it right.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: use async bulc_create, don't save. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create last block, abulc_create

Comment: I think you have to use a decorator for the function to submit changes to the database, this is the decorator needed: @database_sync_to_async but i am no sure because i usually use this with django channels

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comment.  I decided to split the save() and data fetch requests into two separate requests.  One sync and one async.  It's the easiest workaround for now.  Will keep this question open to see if anyone comes up with a clean solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
await sync_to_async(chart.save)
```

should be

```py
await sync_to_async(chart.save)()
```

The `sync_to_async` function wraps `chart.save` and returns an asynchronous version of it, which then still has to be called to execute.

Comment: `await sync_to_async(card.save, thread_sensitive=True)()` does not saves into db

Answer (score 3):

models in Django ≥ 4.2  have the `asave` method